# How to use multiple databases dynamically for one model in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, multiple-databases

Ok, my first question was modified so many times that I chose to delete it and reformulate my question. I've made a small test-case project with different model-names to find a proper solution for my problem.

**Warning**: Don't mix the **databases** up with **tables**

**Motivation**: I separated the user-data into multiple **databases** for legal & performance issues.

Currently I'm working on a **CakePHP** project that has multiple `User`'s and each `User` has it's own **database** with multiple **tables** (`cars` is one of the **tables**). Now, I need to explain something first:

Every `User` has his own **database** (not a table, a **database**), so the database names are as follows.

- [DATABASE] `app` (This is the app's main database)

  - [TABLE] `users`
  - [TABLE] `permissions` (*Not relevant for this question*)
- [DATABASE] `app_user1` (`User.id` 1 owns this entire **database**)

  - [TABLE] `cars` (a **table** entirely owned by `User.id` 1)
- [DATABASE] `app_user2` (`User.id` 2 owns this entire **database**)

  - [TABLE] `cars` (a **table** entirely owned by `User.id` 2)
- etc...

I made a small drawing which might clarify the **database** / **table** -definitions and their relations to the models:

[image: How to use multiple databases dynamically for one model in CakePHP]

**The problem!!!**

I don't know which **database** to connect to until the `User` logs in. `User`'s and their **databases** are created dynamically, so I cant use `app/Config/database.php`.

So I'm currently writing an extension on the `Model` and `ConnectionManager` classes to bypass CakePHP's basic database behaviors. So the `Car` model knows which **database** to use. But I just have a feeling this could be done easier!

So I guess it all boils down to one question:

**Is there an easier way of doing this?!**

Thanks to anyone who will take the time and effort of reading and understanding my problem!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[This gentleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512327/cakephp-switch-database-using-same-datasource-on-the-fly/6058764#6058764) ([Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520129/olivier)) had the same problem! (A year ago) [He wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512327/cakephp-switch-database-using-same-datasource-on-the-fly/6058764#6058764) a small adaptation for the `Controller`s! It's pretty small and it turns out, it works in **1.3** and **2.x**.

Anyhow, this is my final solution, that I put in the `app/Model/AppModel.php`:

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
  /**
   * Connects to specified database
   *
   * @param String name of different database to connect with.
   * @param String name of existing datasource
   * @return boolean true on success, false on failure
   * @access public
   */
    public function setDatabase($database, $datasource = 'default')
    {
      $nds = $datasource . '_' . $database;      
      $db  = &ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource);

      $db->setConfig(array(
        'name'       => $nds,
        'database'   => $database,
        'persistent' => false
      ));

      if ( $ds = ConnectionManager::create($nds, $db->config) ) {
        $this->useDbConfig  = $nds;
        $this->cacheQueries = false;
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
}
```

And here is how I used it in my `app/Controller/CarsController.php`:

```
class CarsController extends AppController
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->Car->setDatabase('cake_sandbox_client3');

    $cars = $this->Car->find('all');

    $this->set('cars', $cars);
  }

}
```

I'm betting, I'm not the first or last one with this problem. So I really hope this information will find people & the CakePHP community.

Comment: Made a few changes, so you can switch **any** model to a different database on the fly, as long as the database-user has the same permissions. You only need to put 1 extra line in you `Controller`

Comment: +1 @ "I'm betting, I'm not the first or last one with this problem. So I really hope this information will find people & the CakePHP community."

Comment: Thank you very much... Your code helped me.. I got `Strict (2048): Only variables should be assigned by reference [APP\Model\AppModel.php, line 46]` but after removing **&** from **$db  = &ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource);** it's working nice

Comment: @ShaunakShukla: It could be that the getDataSource method doesn't retrieve a reference anymore, but a copy of the value instead. In that case you're totally right, it wouldn't work in strict-mode.

Comment: @Ariaan The Error will not come. if you edit above code. You wirte  $db  = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource); instead of $db  = &ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource); . Actually i removed only "&" sign.

Comment: Hello - I am facing the same issue and I used your solution. It works well but the problem I am facing is that when I set the database name in Cars - it does not propagate to other related models. I have to set the database name individually in every model from my controller. Did you solve this scenario by any chance?

Comment: Are you sure you extended your AppModel with the setDatabase function? This handle the switch. I'm not very up to date on CakePhp's current code impl. so if Cake's implementation changed, it might not work anymore. I'll look into it this evening.

Comment: @Ariaan The above is not working for hasOne tables for any model, even if we setDatabase in controller for hasOne table. Any thing i need to do?

Comment: @Anupal, the code should work for any type of table-relation. It mainly switches the database connection. It simply does not interfere with that part of CakePHP. You should probably check your implementation of your solution for 1 database first (without my implementation). It could also be possible that Cake changed their framework to such an extend, it doesn't work anymore. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Ariaan It is v2.5.7 I have implemented the same model which was working with 1 datasource. Its working for 1 level 1 model but not for related tables like hasOne table.

Comment: And you're sure all the tables necessary are accessible in both/all other databases?

Comment: @Ariaan It is connecting to "default" dataSource which i've set when no setDatabase required where no table like this is there.

Comment: @Anupal, So it's not properly connecting to your Alternative DB's. In that case it might be, because Cake's internals has changed, which would mean you need to look for a different implementation. You should be able to see if Cake still implemements it's own ConnectionManager in the same way. I'm afraid I can't help you any further if that's the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78270/discussion-between-anupal-and-ariaan).

Comment: I figured it out using the [Gentleman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512327/cakephp-switch-database-using-same-datasource-on-the-fly) solution.

Comment: I am having issue while connecting each db's in foreach loop one by one. It select 1st database in each loop. Is it cache issue ?

Comment: What is the issue? How many databases are talking about here?

Comment: Urgent: I am having issue while connecting each db's in foreach loop one by one. It selects 1st database in each loop. Is it the cache issue? Please help!

Comment: @Anupal stating the exact same text does not get me closer to understanding.

Comment: @Ariaan There are about 10 databases which i want to connect in loop one by one and then fetch their inner table data.

Comment: @Anupal I never needed more then 5 (because of limited dealers) but I've never run into any physical limits before, what is CakePHP debug telling you about memory usage and script execution time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87641/discussion-between-anupal-and-ariaan).

Answer (score 9):

I don't like the idea of writing down the actual name of the database in the code.
For multiple databases, you have the database.php file where you can set as many databases as you need.

If you want to "switch" a database for a specific model **on the fly**, use the **setDataSource** method. (see [here](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsetDataSource))

For example, if you have two databases, you can define them in the database.php file as "default" and "sandbox", as an example.

Then, in your code:

```
$this->Car->setDataSource('sandbox');
```

The sandbox is the name of the configuration, and the actual name of the database is written only once in the database.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You can always query any databases using full notation in mysql. F.ex.:

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema_name.table_name;
```

Cake way:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$query = array(
    'fields' => array('*'),
    'table' => 'my_schema_name.table_name'
);
$stmt = $db->buildStatement($query, $this);
$result = $db->execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, you are breaking/bypassing the CakePHP conventions from that point forward, within that model.I don't mean to insult but your solution is suitable as a quickfix for models that don't have any deeper relations to other models.

Comment: This solution is for cases where you have hundreds of customer databases and you do not want to create hundreds of database connections to generate, let's say, a summary of data from all customer databases due to performance issues.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. Though it's not what was needed in my case/scenario. Because once a user is logged in, it doesn't require to keep switching databases until a new user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

In your database.php

```
public $mongo = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'database' => 'database_name_mongo',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 27017,
);
```

In your controller you can use

```
$this->Organisation->setDataSource('mongo');
```

then apply query like

```
this->Organisation->find('all');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a folk of the accepted answer. This will prevent the error if the new datasource has already existed:

```
public function setDatabase($database, $datasource = 'default')
{
    $newDatasource = $datasource . '_' . $database;
    try {
        // return the new datasource if it's already existed
        $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($newDatasource);
        $this->useDbConfig  = $newDatasource;
        $this->cacheQueries = false;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // debug($e->getMessage());
    }

    $db  = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource);
    $db->setConfig(array(
        'name'       => $newDatasource,
        'database'   => $database,
        'persistent' => false
    ));

    if ( $ds = ConnectionManager::create($newDatasource, $db->config) ) {
        $this->useDbConfig  = $newDatasource;
        $this->cacheQueries = false;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very elegant, thank you for maintaining the solution :)