# Change database on the fly in Cakephp 1.2 just in some Models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have an application in CakePhp 1.2, where depends on the domain, SOME of the models have to change dinamically the database.

So I need to find an easy way to:

1. Check the domain.
2. Set $useDbConfig on SOME models the database 
   required.

This function on database.php change the database depending just on the domain, but not on the model:

```
public function __construct(){

if (strpos(env('HTTP_HOST'), 'site_one') !== false) {

  // use site_one database config 
  $this->default = $this->site_one;

} elseif (strpos(env('HTTP_HOST'), 'site_two') !== false) {

  // use site_two database config 
  $this->default = $this->site_two; } 

}
```

How can I change the database depending also on the model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223946/how-to-use-multiple-databases-dynamically-for-one-model-in-cakephp

Comment: Please can you update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you used your code, but had an additional database config for those models that don't change?  This additional database config would not be changed by the function you posted.  In those models that you don't want to change, add the line

```
var $useDbConfig = 'static';
```

or whatever the name of your database config is that doesn't change.  Then those that do change, you leave using the default config.

Comment: It works! Amazing! Thank you very much! I was trying to change on the fly the variable $useDbConfig in each model, but I could not to do it.

Comment: I have checked lots of forums, documentation, etc, but I have never found this solucion.

Answer (score 0):

write in your database.php

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'first-database-name',
    'prefix' => '',
);

 var $otherdatabase = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'other-database-name',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

and in model

```
class Modelname extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Modelname';
    var $useTable = 'tablename from other-database';  
    var $useDbConfig = 'otherdatabase ';
    .......... .......... .........
```

Comment: That is the current way, but I need to change $useDbConfig on the fly, depending on the domain. So, it doesn't work.