# Database switch with BindModel in cakePHP

Tags: php, database, cakephp, database-connection

I'm working on application in cake PHP which uses multiple database. I need to fetch data from multiple tables and i'm using bindModel for their association. But bindModel does not allow database switch functionality, I need to access data from multiple databases.If anyone has done this type of assignment then plz help me out.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13224580/1868660

Answer (score 0):

In your AppModel

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
  /**
   * Connects to specified database
   */
    public function setDatabase($database, $datasource = 'default')
    {
      $nds = $datasource . '_' . $database;      
      $db  = &ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource);

      $db->setConfig(array(
        'name'       => $nds,
        'database'   => $database,
        'persistent' => false
      ));

      if ( $ds = ConnectionManager::create($nds, $db->config) ) {
        $this->useDbConfig  = $nds;
        $this->cacheQueries = false;
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
}
```

and in your controller you can use

```
class CarsController extends AppController
{
  public function user()
  {
    $this->User->setDatabase('testdb1');
    $cars = $this->User->find('all');
    $this->set('User', $User);
  }

  public function client()
  {
    $this->Client->setDatabase('testdb2');
    $cars = $this->User->find('all');
    $this->set('Client', $Client);
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm already using this config but i need to switch database while using bindModel function. If i write simple query in code and switch database than thats works for me but if i need bindModel then it does n't works. I think now u got my problem