# populate cascading dropdown from multiple database in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cascadingdropdown

I have 2 database let say DB A and DB B, here is the recap:
DB A has:

```
 - tbl_a
 - tbl_b
 - tbl_c
 - tbl_d
```

DB B has:

```
 - tbl_x
 - tbl_y
```

tbl_d has:

```
tbl_a.id, tbl_b.id, tbl_c.id, tbl_x.id, tbl_y.name
```

I want add data into tbl_d using cascade dropdown list
I already success in making dropdown list to get list of `tbl_a.id, tbl_b.id, tbl_c.id` with `tbl_a.id` as parent but still can't get data for `tbl_x.id` and `tbl_y.name`.

I get complicacy when try retriving list of tbl_x.id because:

1. the database was different but still in 1 server and using same username and password
2. tbl_x only has relation with tbl_a which tbl_x.description = tbl_a.name

here is my add function in Controller:

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->D->create();


        Controller::loadModel('C');
        $data = $this->C->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'C.id' => $this->request->data['D']['c_id']
            )
        ));
        $this->request->data['D']['c_name'] = $data['C']['name'];


                    $this->loadModel('X','Y');
                    $x = $this->X->find('list',array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'X.x_number' => $this->request->data['D']['x_no']
                        )
                    ));
                    $this->set('X',$x);
                    $y = $this->Y->find('list', array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Y.code' => $this->request->data['D']['y_code']
                        )
                    ));
                    $this->set('Y',$y);

        if ($this->D->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data has been saved.'), 'success');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $a = $this->D->A->find('list');

    $types = array(
            'prepaid' => 'Prepaid',
            'postpaid' => 'Postpaid',
            'hybrid' => 'Hybrid'
    );
    $this->set(compact('a', 'types'));
}
```

here is some of my view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('D'); ?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('a_id', array('empty' => '-- Select  --', 'default' => '-- Select  --'));
    echo $this->Form->input('b_id', array('empty' => '-- Select  --'));
    echo $this->Form->input('c_id', array('empty' => '-- Select  --'));
    echo $this->Form->input('x_no', array('options' => $x,
                'class' => 'span5'));
    echo $this->Form->input('y');
    echo $this->Form->input('type');
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Can anyone give me idea how I should do it?

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223946/how-to-use-multiple-databases-dynamically-for-one-model-in-cakephp

Comment: What is your exact problem? Is your problem `$this->X->find` does not return any results? If so, did you see if the SQL being generated is correct? Also, you need to tell us which version of Cakephp you are using.

Comment: my problem is when user select a_id then form input x_no show  some list of x_no based on a_id.
i already did some sql query test and give me what I want.
i'using cakephp version 2.6

Comment: Improved code formatting