# cakephp dynamically database selection

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, default

I have 2 database called database1, database2 in my cakephp application.
before login I have drop down of database(database1,database2).

If user selects **database1** then **databse1** should be default database for application

and if user selects **database2** from drop down then **database2** should be default database for application

below is my default database code

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database1',
    'prefix' => 'tbl_',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223946/how-to-use-multiple-databases-dynamically-for-one-model-in-cakephp plz check this url . hope this will help

Comment: I have checked that link.But in that link they have  set database in function.but in my application I have all controller same for the both database.