# Cakephp can't change database on-the-fly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, saas

I am trying to connect from multiples databases from a loop, but seens CakePHP can't change `database`, only others infos (like user/pass/host).

**app/Config/database.php**

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    [...]

    public $default = array(
        [..] // Where I have the companies
    );
    public $client = array(
        [...] // Fakke settings, because I will change it on-the-fly
    );
}
```

**app/Controller/CronController.php**

```
$companies = $this->Company->find('all');
foreach($companies as $company) {
    $settings = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'host' => $company['Company']['host'],
        'login' => $company['Company']['username'],
        'password' => $company['Company']['password'],
        'database' => $company['Company']['database'],
    );

    ConnectionManager::drop('client');
    $db = ConnectionManager::create('client', $settings);

    try {
        debug($this->MyModel->find('first'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo "Exception: ",  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

        /*
        debug($this->MyModel->getDataSource());

        Outputs:

        [...]
        [config] => Array
            (
                [persistent] => 
                [host] => 0.0.0.0 // CORRECT HOST
                [login] => root // CORRECT LOGIN
                [password] => pass // CORRECT PASSWORD
                [database] => database1
                [port] => 3306
                [datasource] => Database/Mysql
                [prefix] => 
                [encoding] => utf8
            )
        [...]
        */
    }
}
```

It return the first connection and all others I can select nothing from MyModel, because it is wrong. It seens connection from user/password/host is ok, but, database are not changed, so, because user haven't permission to select on cdatabase, I get the error.

```
Array
(
    // First connection, connection ok, MyModel return nothing
)

// Second connection
Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'database_user_2'@'localhost' for table 'my_model'

// Third connection
Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'database_user_3'@'localhost' for table 'my_model'

// Fourth connection
Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'database_user_4'@'localhost' for table 'my_model'

// Fifth connection
Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'database_user_5'@'localhost' for table 'my_model'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512327/cakephp-switch-database-using-same-datasource-on-the-fly

Comment: @Steve Yes, but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to drop config, just alter the things you need.

For this task I successfully use

```
$dataSource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('company_data');
$dataSource->config['schema'] = 'company_'.$id;
```

I don't know if database switching and mysql as engine is good pair. I use postgresql schemas for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the model method [setSource()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsetSource) to change the table or [setDataSource()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsetDataSource) to change the db config.