# Dynamically change database connection in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to change the database connection used in **cakephp 3** on the fly. Every answer to this question that I found refers to **cakephp 2** ([These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655613/multiple-databases-with-cakephp-setting-database-name-from-controller-to-model) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223946/how-to-use-multiple-databases-dynamically-for-one-model-in-cakephp) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956791/cakephp-cant-change-database-on-the-fly) instance).

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981890/multiple-database-connection-in-cakephp-3) found a solution for **cakephp 3** having a finite number of databases, and specifically defining which Database would be used by which Table file.

The thing is that I want to create a new database for every new user, and change to his database when he logs in. I can't know in advance all the databases that will exist, to write it in the `config/app.php` file.

And I can't set the default database in each /src/Model/Table file, because the tables are the same in every database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `ConnectionManager::config()` function to create connections on the fly and the `ConnnectionManager::alias()` method to make all your Table classes use it by default.

There is a very good article describing the process here:

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-cakephp-and-a-horizontally-sharded-database

The only difference is that you can create the connection config on the fly instead of declaring the shards manually as it was shown in that article.

Comment: Based on Mark's article I added middleware (CakePHP 3) to create an alias based on form request data, effectively allowing a database change on the fly/at login - see https://gist.github.com/chopstik/9fcfc21de0a657986c5974fdf2abd402#file-application-php

Answer (score 1):

Change database connection for one model:

In app.php :

```js
'test' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => MySQL_HOST,
            //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
            'port' => MySQL_PORT,
            'username' => MySQL_USER,
            'password' => MySQL_PASS,
            'database' => 'test',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        ]
```

In Controller :

```js
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('test');
 $_model = TableRegistry::get('your_alias', ['table' => 'your_table', 'connection' => $conn]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Configuring table connections](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-table-connections)

```
 namespace App\Model\Table;

 use Cake\ORM\Table;

 class ArticlesTable extends Table
 {
     public static function defaultConnectionName() {
     return 'replica_db';
     }
 }
```