# change default db in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In a controller I want to change the default database so i can access the new db (db2) from anywhere in the website. The db2 database has the same models but just different data. My code just accesses the other database but doesnt set the new default database to db2 which can be accessed anywhere in the website. I didnt get the answer from the below posts.

**This is my controller :**

```php
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('db2'); // 'db2' where my second database is configured 
$results = $connection->execute('SELECT * FROM tutors')->fetchAll('assoc');
//this works but doesnt set the default database to db2 everywhere
```

**This is my app.php :**

```php
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',

        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'aptutori_test',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => '+11:00',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,

        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],

    'db2' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',

        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'aptutori_testbak',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => '+11:00',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,

        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
```

[Dynamically change database connection in cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262176/dynamically-change-database-connection-in-cakephp-3)

http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-cakephp-and-a-horizontally-sharded-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ConnectionManager::alias()`:

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.ConnectionManager.html#_alias

Fore example this will make all tables that require the `default` connection to use `db2`:

```
ConnectionManager::alias('db2', 'default');
```

Comment: I need this to work for every controller so I need to set this globally . My issue is that the database (code above)only changes for the controllers functions but I have about 30 controllers.

Comment: how do i set this change globally across all controllers/models

Comment: Tthe AppController class is the parent class to all of your application’s controllers

Comment: how do i set a global variable in a controller which then gets set in the appcontroller.

Comment: set it in the beforeFilter of your appController and then every controller will use it.

Comment: Hi, I dont get what to do because to have to get user interaction to manually set a database , so that involves sending the appcontroller a variable from a controller  to then set the database required. .

Comment: save it somewhere, maybe in the db itself, a file, a cookie, web sql. somewhere and then use it in the appController

Comment: I dont disagree with what your saying I just dont get the code to go backward from a regular controller to the appcontroller and setting a global variable for a multi user application. I really cant find an example either about doing this . I dont want to save in a db or file

Comment: where do you wanna save then?

Comment: I want to not save it in the appcontroller. as  the appcontroller just reads the desired db to load

Answer (score 0):

You could do this application wide in a Middleware in > cake 3.3, opposed to using a DispatcherFilter, like described in http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-cakephp-and-a-horizontally-sharded-database.

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class TenantShardMiddleware
{

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {

        $tenant = $request->getHeader('MY-tenant');
        ConnectionManager::alias($tenant[0], 'default');
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

In my example above I'm using a special Request Header to switch databases.