# create multiple database connection at runtime

Tags: php, database, cakephp, runtime

I have a table that contains all database name. I want to create a run time database connection in CakePHP and search data in the database. Is there any way in CakePHP to fetch database name from default database and create runtime connection?

Comment: Don't know if this helps $this->db = & ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default'); in controller and then use this connection

Comment: Hi Keyur,
               thank you but i have a table that contain all database name . condition is that i want to search something .if it is found in first database than no need of second connection otherwise need to create connection with second database.

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262176/dynamically-change-database-connection-in-cakephp-3

Comment: this is fine but not great

Comment: If you have a finite number of databases then I think you could create that many connections in app/config.php and then use them on fly as needed

Comment: How to use it. i use on fly but in my model it use default datasource what to do

Comment: Try $this->db = & ConnectionManager::getDataSource(YOUR_DATABASE_NAME);