# CakePHP multiple databases connection in foreach loop issue

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, database-connection, multiple-databases

I am using the Cake for connecting multiple databases in a loop with having same database user config. I just use this method for making different connection on the fly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058764/1668476

I just use this in a `AppController` function and then in all my controller with
Here is the function to connect with database on the fly:

```
//Used for connecting different databases on the fly
function dbConnect($database, $dataSource = 'default', $prefix = 'mycake_') {
        ClassRegistry::init('ConnectionManager');
        $database = $prefix.$database;
        $nds = $dataSource . '_' . $database;
        $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($dataSource);
        $db->setConfig(array('name' => $nds, 'database' => $database, 'persistent' => false));
        if($ds = ConnectionManager::create($nds, $db->config)) return $db->config;
        return false;
    }
```

Then in eevery controller is just use `useDbConfig` like:

`$newDbConfig = $this->dbConnect($serverConfig);
$this->Summary->useDbConfig = $newDbConfig['name'];`

**Problem:** Problem is when i try to fetch each of the summary table data in foreach loop. Every time it runs it always keep connects with 1st databases only. Here is the loop:

```
foreach($this->databases as $key=> $database){
      $newDbConfig = $this->dbConnect($database);
      $this->Summary->useDbConfig = $newDbConfig['name'];
      $this->Summary->cacheQueries = false;
      $summary = $this->Summary->findAllByPeriod('1');
      debug(count($summary));
}
```

I tried to use `clearCache()` or `connectionManager:drop()` but with no success.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Call setSource

The property `useDbConfig` is not the right/best way to change the datasource of an in-use model. To change the data source at run time, call [setDataSource](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3607-L3638), i.e.:

```
foreach($this->databases as $key=> $database){
      $newDbConfig = $this->dbConnect($database);
      $this->Summary->setDataSource($newDbConfig['name']);
      ...
}
```

Comment: which would be best in performance? `useDbConfig` OR `setDataSource` ?

Comment: Actually i am thinking to change it all over in my controllers.